# Woocommerce. Проверка и предотвращение смены статуса заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, order

Мне нужно предотвратить изменение статуса заказа при определенных условиях. Например, заказ не может иметь статус «завершен», пока ему не присвоен номер дорожки транспортной компании. Другой пользовательский статус («cdek»), который автоматически выполняет регистрацию в службе доставки и может быть установлен только для отдельных заказов.Таким образом, решения о принудительном изменении статуса не подходят назад. Требуется именно предотвращение изменения статуса, чтобы не было выполнено никаких условий, связанных с установленным статусом.Я уже видел некоторые неуместные решения и обсуждения подобных задач:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/23009
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569105/woocommerce-hook-before-order-status-change

`woocommerce_before_order_object_save` выглядит наиболее подходящим, и я пытаюсь разобраться, как отображать сообщения об ошибках в различных ситуациях - групповое редактирование, одиночное, ajax ... (может быть, нужно рассмотреть что-то еще)?

eng: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165499/woocommerce-prevent-change-order-status

Comment: order - это пост тип, то есть на save_post вы можете повлиять на сохранение

Comment: я пробовал `wp_insert_post_data`,  однако не получил должного результата - не везде оно работает,

Comment: предположительно нашел решение с  
 `woocommerce_before_order_object_save` и `wp_redirect`,   
если будет кому-то нужно, выложу тут